# Android Canvas.drawCircle() bug. Persistently draws an ellipse instead of a circle

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, geometry

I try to create a circle with help of Canvas, using the method drawCircle(...). But in the end why get I an ellipse instead of a circle ? How can I get "true" circle ?

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (widthView), heightView, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF950000"));
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
  canvas.drawRect(0.0f, 0.0f, widthView, heightLevel, paint);
  paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD4A503"));
  canvas.drawRect(0.0f, heightLevel, widthView, 2 * heightLevel, paint);
  paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4A7816"));
  canvas.drawRect(0.0f, 2 * heightLevel, widthView, 3 * heightLevel,
    paint);
  paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
  canvas.drawCircle(30 * density, getLevelHeight(1), 20f, paint);  graphicView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
    bitmap));
```

**Result:**

Nexus 4

[image]

Huawei G500Pro (Shine)

[image]

Comment: Try using `setImageBitmap()` instead of `setBackgroundDrawable()`

Comment: Thank you, this help me. Pls do your comment as an answer - I will vote up (best answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setImageBitmap(Bitmap)` in place of `setBackgroundDrawable()`.

Moreover, `setBackgroundDrawable()` has been deprecated.

Comment: How is this related, can you care to explain

Comment: @Manish I cannot explain this Manish. Look at the comments to the question. I suggested using `setImageBitmap()` because it seemed like the OP was trying to set the content of `graphicView` rather than its background. I didn't have a clue that it would solve the problem. Why it did solve the problem is a mystery to me.